# Is it possible to visualize hbase table using Javascript

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, hbase, cluster-analysis, data-visualization

I am new to HBase. Here is my problem.

I have a very large HBase table. An example data in the table.

```
1003:15:Species1:MONTH:01 0.1,02 0.7,03 0.3,04 0.1,05 0.1,06 0,07 0,08 0,09 0.1,10 0.2,11 0.3,12 0.1:LATITUDE 26.664503840000002 29.145674380000003,LONGITUDE -96.27139215 -90.40762858
```

As you can see for each **Species** there is a month attribute (12 vectors), Lat & Long, etc. There are around 300 unique species and several 1000 observations for one particular species.

I have written a Mapreduce job which does **K-means clustering** on one particular species. The output of my MR is

```
C1:1003:15:Species1:MONTH:01 0.1,02 0.7,03 0.3,04 0.1,05 0.1,06 0,07 0,08 0,09 0.1,10 0.2,11 0.3,12 0.1:LATITUDE 26.664503840000002 29.145674380000003,LONGITUDE -96.27139215 -90.40762858
```

The C1 indicates which cluster it belongs to.
Now I want to visualize the output i.e plot all the Lat and Long for each cluster on a Map. I was thinking of using [Mapbox.js](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/vectors-with-d3/) and [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) for my data visualization, since the Lat and Longs in the data are bounding boxes for a particular region.

**If I write the o/p of my MR back to Hbase is it possible to retrive the data using javascript on the client side ?**

I was thinking of either writing the data to **MongoDB** which I can query using JS or write a program to **create a JSON** from the Hbase table which I can visualize. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can't you just set up a REST service or so and parse the HBase query results to JSON? I did set up a Thrift service that queries HBase when my client applications (C# and Java) call the service. My client application than plots the data (MSChart in C# and JFreeChart in Java). Works quite well. Or don't I understand your case very well?

Comment: Oh so your server will be a java server which takes a query from the client and returns the Hbase data ?

Comment: That is indeed exactly what I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [HBAse REST API](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/HbaseRest) though security-wise it is probably safer to put your own service in the middle

Comment: Exactly what I would recommend as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use node-hbase from https://github.com/alibaba/node-hbase-client to read the hbase data

Answer (score 1):

you can also use hbase-rpc-client https://github.com/falsecz/hbase-rpc-client to read data from nodejs. This client supports hbase 0.96+